# How to use pywin32 functions in C++ code?

Tags: python, windows, com, pywin32

What would be the easiest way to start using `pywin32` package functions in C++ code?

I am building a Python wrapper for a Windows COM-based library and I would like to use
`PyObject *PyCom_PyObjectFromVariant(const VARIANT *var);`
function from `pywin32` package in my C++ wrapper code.

Should I compile the "pywin32" DLL and just copy the `.h` files to my project? Or is there a more straightforward way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I want to answer my own question:

To use pywin32 or win32com functions you need to install pywin32 package and include the following directories in C++ project:

```
site-packages/win32/include
site-packages/win32com/include
```

and include library paths:

```
site-packages/win32/libs
site-packages/win32com/libs
```